# De Rham Cohomology of Hopf Surface

Tags: differential-geometry

How I calculate the De Rham coohomology of the Hopf surface? In particular I would like to know why the second Betti number is zero .

Comment: I'm trying to use the Kunnet formula. Am I doing right ?

Comment: What is your definition of a Hopf surface ? The quotient of $\mathbb C^2-\{0\}$ by what kind of discrete group ?

Comment: Yes, sorry my fault. In particular  $C^2−{0}/(x,y) /sim (2x,2y)$. I know that it's diffeomorphic to $S^1XS^3$

Comment: Also how i prove this last fact, that it's diffeomorphic to $S^1XS^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be the complex surface given by $\mathbb C^2-\{0\}/\mathbb Z$ where $\gamma:(z_1,z_2)\mapsto (2z_1,2z_2)$ generate $\mathbb Z$.

The first step is to check that the map $$z=(z_1,z_2)\mapsto \left(\dfrac{z}{\|z\|},\log(\|z\|)\right)$$ induces a diffeomorphism between $\mathbb C^2-\{0\}$ and $S^3\times \mathbb R$ (this is just the polar coordinates system).

Then, the action of $\mathbb Z$ on the $S^3\times \mathbb R$ is exactly given by $(x,t)\in S^3\times \mathbb R\mapsto (x,t+\log(2))$ so the quotient $X=\mathbb C^2-\{0\}/\mathbb Z$ is diffeomorphic to $S^3\times S^1$.

Finally, if you know the cohomology of the $n$-sphere, then $$H_k(X)\simeq H_k(S^3\times S^1) \simeq \bigoplus_{i+j=k} H_i(S^3)\otimes H_j(S^1)$$
and you get $H_2(X)$ easily.